# Encrypt an image using openssl

Tags: security

I have a .bmp image. I wanted to encrypt the image file using openssl command. The following is the command I have used to encrypt the image.

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -in pic_original.bmp -out aes128cbc.bmp -K 00112233445566778889aabbccddeeff -iv 0102030405060708
```

As per ECB mode is concerned I should be able to view partial image when I encrypt the file using ECB mode however I cannot see the image at all. The image viewing software says there is bogus header data

Is there any thing wrong in the command I used for encrypting the file. Can someone help me with this please

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to view part of the file? You just encrypted the whole file, both header and data.

Comment: I was going through the wikipedia of symmetric ciphers and there it shows the difference when the image is encrypted with the ECB mode and then one with CFB and etc., So was curious to know how come my encryption doesn't show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you encrypted everything, including header. You should extract bitmap data into a raw stream, encrypt that and attach header back to it.

Comment: I am a newbie so just wanted to know how do I extract the bitmap data into a raw stream. Should I have write any C code for doing that or is there any software to make out lives easier.

Comment: You can try combinations of tools from Netpbm or ImageMagick, or script something quickly in Python using PIL http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily copy the header back on top of the image:

```
dd if=/path/oldfile.bmp of=newfile.bmp bs=54 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

To learn about dd:

```
man dd
```

You can search for examples of this on the web .[E. Hugo's blog](http://myhackingjournal.blogspot.com/2016/10/encryption-and-decryption-of-images.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the header from the original image and use it to replace the header of the encrypted file.  Generally for a bmp file, the first 54 bytes contain the header info.

to do this:

```
head -c 54 pic_og.bmp > header
tail -c +55 pic_cbc.bmp > body_cbc
cat header body_cbc > new_enc_cbc.bmp
```